# useState() not updating value with setter function

Tags: react-native

I have

```
function Meal(props) {
    const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

    const setFavorite = () => {
        setIsFavorite(currentStatus => !currentStatus);
    };
    render (etc...)
}
```

When Calling setFavorite, the `isFavorite` is not changed. Why?
I have read a lot of questions on StackOverflow around it and I still do not get the logic. I tried using `useEffect` but without success.

Comment: Could you specify how you are calling setFavorite?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
> function Meal(props) {
>        const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);
>    
>        const handleFavorite = () => {
>            setIsFavorite(!isFavorite);
>        };
>        render (etc...)    }
```

where handleFavorite function triggers the action (if it's called onClick, onChange or something else)

Comment: Hi @Azra, this did not do the trick unfortunately. Can you clarify how this is different from what I have been doing?